# How to bind a check button to a function in abaqus python scripting?

Tags: python, abaqus

I have a check button (created using FXCheckButton) in a python code written under abaqus scripting module. I want to bind this check bottun with a function, but don't know how. I know in the wx.Python we only need to do this command:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.Func1, self.checkButton1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I found:

```
FXCheckButton(p=form, text= 'Text', tgt=form.keywordKw, sel=0)
msgCount1 = 1
form.keywordKw.setTarget(self)
form.keywordKw.setSelector(AFXDataDialog.ID_LAST+msgCount1)
FXMAPFUNC(self, SEL_COMMAND, form.keywordKw.getSelector(), yourPythonClassName.yourFunctionName)
```